# поиск и подсчет нужного значения из dbgrid

Tags: delphi-7, datagrid, label

Добрый день суток. наткнулся на такую проблему. хочу чтобы в dbgrd из столбце 'transactionname' посчитать значение 'Продажа' и отобразить в lbl. Помогите пожалуйста.
lbl4.Caption := dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(('transactionname').AsString='Продажа'.RecordCount);

Comment: было но я не получил не каких ответов и подумал значит что мой вопрос был не понят и заново отправил вопрос))

Comment: Боюсь что вопрос довольно сложный. По идее `Lookup` вам поможет.. Возможно `Filter` поможет, но при этом "Грид" будет "прыгать". А что б грид не прыгал...

Comment: @nick_n_a `.DisableControls;` :)

Comment: не помогло DisableControls

Comment: @delphi не помогло - в чем?

Comment: dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(('transactionname').AsString='Продажа'.DisableControls);???

Comment: @delphi Прочитайте, пожалуйста, раздел в Help: `TDataSet.DisableControls` http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_DisableControls.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все получилось!

```
qry2.SQL.Add('select transaction, count(id) as kol from reester where 1=1');

while not qry2.Eof do begin
    if qry2.FieldByName('transaction').AsInteger=1 then lbl4.Caption:='Продажа = '+qry2.FieldByName('kol').AsString;
    if qry2.FieldByName('transaction').AsInteger=2 then lbl5.Caption:='Обмен = '+qry2.FieldByName('kol').AsString;
    if qry2.FieldByName('transaction').AsInteger=3 then lbl6.Caption:='Аннуляция = '+qry2.FieldByName('kol').AsString;
    if qry2.FieldByName('transaction').AsInteger=4 then lbl7.Caption:='Возврат = '+qry2.FieldByName('kol').AsString;
    if qry2.FieldByName('transaction').AsInteger=5 then lbl8.Caption:='МСО = '+qry2.FieldByName('kol').AsString;
    qry2.Next;
  end;
```

Comment: а  где `qry2.Open;`?

Comment: qry2.SQL.Add(' group by transaction');
  qry2.Open;